# Cursor issues on Remove

Tags: php, mongodb

There is no ->remove()->limit() for mongodb.
That's why I use my little script for solving the task.

```
<?php
$conn = new Mongo('127.0.0.1');
$db = $conn->experimentDB;
$experimentCollection = $db->experimentCollection;
foreach($ruleset AS $ruleset_item)
{
    $max_remove_loops=3;
    $max_limit_per_loop=1000;
    MongoCursor::$timeout = 1*60*1000;
    for($remove_loops=0;$remove_loops<$max_remove_loops;$remove_loops++)
    {
        if(!TEST)
            $cursor = $experimentCollection->find($ruleset_item)->limit($max_limit_per_loop);//->skip($remove_loops*$max_limit_per_loop);
        else
            $cursor = $experimentCollection->find($ruleset_item)->limit($max_limit_per_loop)->skip($remove_loops*$max_limit_per_loop);
        $items=0;
        foreach($cursor AS $cursor_item)
        {
            //print_r($cursor_item['_id']);
            print('.');
            if(!TEST)
                $experimentCollection->remove(array('_id' => $cursor_item['_id']));
            $items++;
        }
        if($items==0)
        {
            break;
            print(' that was the last one. DONE ');
        }
        //$cursor->reset();
    }
}
?>
```

This ended up in

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'cursor timed out (timeout: 60000, time left: 0:0, status: 0)'

That's why I tried to split the task with max_remove_loops and max_limit_per_loop and changed the max_limit_per_loop to 1min, 1h, 2h, etc.

However, there seems to be another issue why the script is hanging after few hundred removes. Sometimes anywhere between 200-2000. (It's count by print('.'))

This looks like a random bug and is depending on the other tasks that mongodb has to manage, RAM, CPU load.

Just a guess, but maybe it is causing troubles because of the removes if the loop is catching the same cursor that has been in queue for being removed with a slight delay?

How to fix this script to be fault tolerant and continue instead of hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several improvements can be made here.

For starters, your script only accesses the `_id` field of each document. Therefore, you can explicitly include the `_id` field, and implicitly exclude all other fields, in the projection (i.e. second argument to [MongoCollection::find()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)). This is also described in the [db.collection.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) documentation. A projection is helpful for limiting the amount of data sent back from the server.

Additionally, you should ensure that the queries you're issuing in this script are indexed. When you use a large skip offset, MongoDB first executes the query and then walks through the results individually until a given number have been skipped and it can begin returning results. For un-indexed queries, this can be a very slow process of walking through documents on disk. It can even be slow for indexed queries, depending on the size of the skip. An alternative to using limit/skip for pagination is to utilize range queries, where you pick up from a value greater or less than what you last saw. If you're curious about this method, I would direct you to [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18319714/162228), which includes a few links on the subject.

For debugging the queries and determining if they are indexed, you can use [MongoCursor::explain()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.explain.php). Additional documentation on its return value (such as how to determine if the query is indexed or not) can be found in the [cursor.explain()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) documentation.

Lastly, I would suggest refactoring your script to collect the IDs to remove up front, before removing anything. Assuming your IDs are 12-byte ObjectIds (MongoId objects in PHP), you should have no problem collecting them in an array. This would allow you to walk all of the results for a query without any limit/skip business. Afterwards, you could either issue a series of single-document removes, or issue one or several removes with the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) operator to match several IDs at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the details and references. Most of this has been checked and tried already, but let me jump into your last tip with `$in` is also slowing down. The `find` is processed quickly and the first deletes are also running well. after few seconds, the number of deletes per second become less and less. Of course, I can stop the script after a while and repeat the same. MongoDB's explain does not give me additional insights for finding the reason for the slowliness.

Comment: If you avoid `$in` and just do individual remove operations, do those slow down over time as well? This still assumes you exhaust the first cursor and have collected all IDs up front.