# MongoCursor Positioning Infinite Scroll Application with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am needing to get an infinite scrolling REST API call going.  I have a general approach, but I cannot seem to find the proper syntax for what I am trying to accomplish.  Essentially, the Web-App sends me a call to get a list of posts, simple enough.  Now the user has scrolled past the first 100 I loaded up.  Now, how do I get a `MongoCursor` to start from where I left off?

Do I send the app an `int` and they return that and I just do a `$cursor->find()->skip($x)`?

I am thinking that somehow I send the app my cursor, and then it will send the cursor back when it is ready for more results, and I just re-connect it and it continues?

I've found this tutorial - http://artsy.github.io/blog/2013/02/15/infinite-scroll-with-mongodb/ but I cannot seem to grasp what parameters they are sending and why?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Comment: You've basically got it ..., `skip` to the current starting index (an integer), and you may want to `limit` to retrieve only a "pages" worth of data. Or, depending on your data, if you could sort on a field and always do a `$gt` the last value displayed, it would be very efficient.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle pagination queries properly with mongodb and php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010744/how-to-handle-pagination-queries-properly-with-mongodb-and-php)

Comment: 'Tis a duplicate.  Wish I found that post before I made this.  Thanks, @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 0):

> I've found this tutorial -
>   http://artsy.github.io/blog/2013/02/15/infinite-scroll-with-mongodb/
>   but I cannot seem to grasp what parameters they are sending and why?

Pagination and infinite scrolling are best implemented with range queries, which the blog post you cited demonstrates. Skip and limit are conceptually simple, and are actually quite fine if we're only dealing with a few pages, but performance starts to fall off drastically as the page counts increase into the hundreds.

When you issue a query (hopefully indexed) with a skip, MongoDB needs to go to the first result and walk forward "skip" number of times. For indexed queries, this means walking the index, which may not be entirely in memory. Contrast this to a range query that does not use skip, where our criteria requests data greater or less than that which we've last seen, MongoDB is able to jump right to the first result and we need only iterate through "limit" documents.

The following answer and blog posts explain the subject in more detail:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704204/162228
- [MongoDB Pagination – using range queries](http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongodb-pagination-using-range-queries.html)
- [MongoDB Paging using Ranged Queries (Avoiding Skip())](https://sammaye.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/mongodb-paging-using-ranged-queries-avoiding-skip/)